# SAS: Is it possible to store a compiled macro in a catalog other than sasmacr?

Tags: sas

SAS macros are compiled and stored into a catalog named sasmacr. Is there a way to store them in a catalog with a different name?

The use case is a test harness where I wish to create a collection of test case macros in a namespace where they cannot clash with macros defined in the program being tested. My workaround is to prefix all my test macros' names with what I believe is a unique string.

Answer (score 3):

From the [SAS Site](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001328769.htm)

```
libname mymacs 'SAS-data-library';
filename mymacros catalog 'mymacs.myautos';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can by using the system options MAUTOSOURCE and SASAUTOS to direct SAS where to search for stored macros.